# Multithreading doesn't work if I start more than 1 other thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I don't know if this problem is Unity-specific so maybe other C# developers can help me too :)

So I am actually trying to implement my own version of the A* algorithm and to improve performance I want the actual path finding for every seeker to be multi threaded:

[image: One active seeker]

It works pretty well until the moment I activate a second seeker:
[image: Two active seekers]

Like you can see it stops after 15 iterations (varying depending on how many text outputs i call -> I guess the threads are getting killed after a amount of time) in the algorithm and the first started thread gets kind of killed by the following.

I am using the C# `ThreadPool` class for my thread management but I tried also to use the `Thread` class. It is the same result.

Implementation of my threading:

```
public static void RequestPath(PathRequest _request)
{
    Debug.Log("Queueing PathRequest...");
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(instance.StartThreadedPathfinding, _request);
}
```

The called method:

```
private void StartThreadedPathfinding(object _stateInfo)
{
    PathRequest request = (PathRequest)_stateInfo;
    m_pathfinder.FindPath(request, OnPathFound);
}
```

And `FindPath`:

```
public void FindPath(PathRequest _request, Action<PathResult> _callback)
{
    Debug.Log("Starting A* Algorithm");
    BinaryHeap<Node> openList = new BinaryHeap<Node>(GridSize);
    HashSet<Node> closedList = new HashSet<Node>();

    Node startNode = _request.Start;
    Node targetNode = _request.Target;

    bool success = false;

    openList.Add(startNode);

    while (openList.Count > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ": " + Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState.ToString());
        Node currentNode = openList.RemoveFirst();

        if (currentNode == targetNode)
        {
            // TODO: Path found -> _callback
            success = true;
            Debug.Log("Path found");
            _callback(new PathResult(null, success, _request.Callback));
            return;
        }

        closedList.Add(currentNode);

        foreach (Node neighbour in currentNode.m_neighbours)
        {
            if (closedList.Contains(neighbour))
            {
                continue;
            }

            int tentativeG = currentNode.m_gCost + GetDistance(currentNode, neighbour);
            if (openList.Contains(neighbour) && tentativeG > neighbour.m_gCost)
            {
                continue;
            }

            neighbour.m_parent = currentNode;
            neighbour.m_gCost = tentativeG;
            neighbour.m_hCost = GetDistance(neighbour, targetNode);

            if (openList.Contains(neighbour))
            {
                openList.UpdateItem(neighbour);
            }
            else
            {
                openList.Add(neighbour);
            }
        }
    }

    // TODO: No path to the target exists -> calculate some path
    success = false;
    Debug.Log("No existing path");
    _callback(new PathResult(null, success, _request.Callback));
    return;
}
```

`RequestPath` and `StartThreadedPathfinding` are in a class called `PathRequestManager` and `FindPath` is in an other class called `Pathfinder`.

Another point is that the threads don't just stop because of an error or sth like that but are still somehow running I think because after I started the scene in Unity I have to kill the Unity-process in the taskmanager because sth is stuck (CPU-Load is always about 80% when I have to do that)
Thought about deadlocks but couldn't find any.

I would be glad if someone could help me here and if you need more information about the source code feel free to ask :)

Comment: Generally you don't want to swawn threads for this type of thing.  Better to use progressive deferred computation over a series of frames in the primary thread

Comment: And how to do that?

Comment: Try to look up `StartCoroutine`. And because Unity's default Coroutine sucks the community has developed an awesome asset: More Effective Coroutines (free) and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem thanks to an answer in the [Unity forums](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1340702/multithreading-doesnt-work-if-i-start-more-then-1.html):

I was working on the same `Grid` and therefore on the same `Nodes` with every thread. When I was updating a `Node` in the algorithm on one thread while another one was working with the same `Node` some bad things happend and the result can be seen above in the question.

I solved this by cloning the grid for each thread and working on the grids owned by the threads.